# How do I make these functions shorter

Tags: javascript, function

I was making a simple calculator with two input boxes for each number, and four buttons for each operation underneath. After pressing one of the buttons (Ex:Add) They would perform the operation. However, inside each function I had to keep writing these two lines:

```
var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').valueAsNumber;
var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').valueAsNumber;
```

Is there a way I could write these before I make each individual function? Could someone with more skill possibly show me what I could do?

```js
function add() {
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').valueAsNumber;
    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').valueAsNumber;
    var Total = Value1 + Value2;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Total: " + Total;
}
function sub() {
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').valueAsNumber;
    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').valueAsNumber;
    var Total = Value1 - Value2;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Total: " + Total;
}
function mul() {
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').valueAsNumber;
    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').valueAsNumber;
    var Total = Value1 * Value2;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Total: " + Total;
}
function div() {
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').valueAsNumber;
    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').valueAsNumber;
    var Total = Value1 / Value2;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Total: " + Total;
}
```

```html
First Number: <input type="number" id="Value1"><br><br>
Second Number: <input type="number" id="Value2"><br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button type="button" onclick="sub()">Subtract</button>
<button type="button" onclick="mul()">Multiply</button>
<button type="button" onclick="div()">Divide</button>
<p id="demo" style="color:red;font-size:20px"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I could write these before I make each individual function?

You can get the *elements* just once:

```
const input1 = document.getElementById("Value1");
```

Then when you need its value:

```
const value1 = input1.valueAsNumber;
```

In general, you can usually write a function to avoid duplicated logic. Probably not appropriate in this case, but for example:

```
function getValueAsNumber(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).valueAsNumber;
}
```

then

```
const value1 = getValueAsNumber("Value1");
```

---

A couple of side notes:

- In JavaScript and related languages, the overwhelming convention is to use an initial lower case letter for variables that don't refer to constructor functions. So `value1` rather than `Value1`, `value1Element` rather than `Value1Element`, etc.
- `var` is no longer best practice in JavaScript. In new code, prefer `let` or `const` because of their more useful scoping.
- When putting just plain text in an element, you're better off using `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`, because the browser doesn't try to parse the text you give it as HTML.
- `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers are not best practice, not least because the functions they call have to be globals, and the global namespace is crowded. Consider using modern event handling ([`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the like).

Just for an example, here's your code with some of the above applied, but without going overboard:

```js
const gid = id => document.getElementById(id);
const input1 = gid("Value1");
const input2 = gid("Value2");
const demo = gid("demo");

gid("add").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const total = input1.valueAsNumber + input2.valueAsNumber;
    demo.textContent = "Total: " + total;
});

gid("sub").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const total = input1.valueAsNumber - input2.valueAsNumber;
    demo.textContent = "Total: " + total;
});

gid("mul").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const total = input1.valueAsNumber * input2.valueAsNumber;
    demo.textContent = "Total: " + total;
});

gid("div").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const total = input1.valueAsNumber / input2.valueAsNumber;
    demo.textContent = "Total: " + total;
});
```

```html
First Number: <input type="number" id="Value1"><br><br>
Second Number: <input type="number" id="Value2"><br><br>
<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" id="sub">Subtract</button>
<button type="button" id="mul">Multiply</button>
<button type="button" id="div">Divide</button>
<p id="demo" style="color:red;font-size:20px"></p>
```

Or we could abstract away everything but the operation itself (just for fun):

```js
const gid = id => document.getElementById(id);
const input1 = gid("Value1");
const input2 = gid("Value2");
const demo = gid("demo");
const clickHandler = (id, operation) => {
//                        ^^^^^^^^^
    gid(id).addEventListener("click", () => {
        const total = operation(input1.valueAsNumber, input2.valueAsNumber);
        //            ^^^^^^^^^
        demo.textContent = "Total: " + total;
    });
};
clickHandler("add", (a, b) => a + b);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
clickHandler("sub", (a, b) => a - b);
clickHandler("mul", (a, b) => a * b);
clickHandler("div", (a, b) => a / b);
```

```html
First Number: <input type="number" id="Value1"><br><br>
Second Number: <input type="number" id="Value2"><br><br>
<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" id="sub">Subtract</button>
<button type="button" id="mul">Multiply</button>
<button type="button" id="div">Divide</button>
<p id="demo" style="color:red;font-size:20px"></p>
```

You could even go further than that, but it starts getting hard to follow. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function to get the value of an element by ID, and re-use it, also you can create 1 function that will show the total as well.

```js
function showTotal(total) {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
}

function getValue(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).valueAsNumber;
}

function add() {
    showTotal(getValue("Value1") + getValue("Value2"));
}
function sub() {
    showTotal(getValue("Value1") - getValue("Value2"));
}
function mul() {
    showTotal(getValue("Value1") * getValue("Value2"));
}
function div() {
    showTotal(getValue("Value1") / getValue("Value2"));
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center"><br><br>
    First Number: <input type="number" id="Value1"><br><br>
    Second Number: <input type="number" id="Value2"><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="sub()">Subtract</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="mul()">Multiply</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="div()">Divide</button>
    <p id="demo" style="color:red;font-size:20px"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Let's separate the calculating from the formatted displaying.  We'll have one function to calculate (`+`, `-`, `/`, `*`) and a different function to handle `innerHTML`-setting.
- Since the calculations are all in one function, that removes the redundancy of multiple `document.getElementById` calls throughout your code.
- We can use a [`switch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement to determine the operation to apply, although a standard [`if()`/`else()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) also would work.

Working demo...

```js
function operate(e) {
    var Total = getOperationTotal(e);
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Total: " + Total;
}

function getOperationTotal(e) {
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').valueAsNumber;
    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').valueAsNumber;
    var total;
    switch(e.target.id) {
         case 'add-button':
               total = Value1 + Value2;
               break;
         case 'subtract-button':
               total = Value1 - Value2;
               break;
         case 'multiply-button':
               total = Value1 * Value2;
               break;
         case 'divide-button':
               total = Value1 / Value2;
               break;
    }
    return total;
}
```

```html
First Number: <input type="number" id="Value1"><br><br>
Second Number: <input type="number" id="Value2"><br><br>

<button id="add-button" type="button" onclick="operate(event)">Add</button>
<button id="subtract-button" type="button" onclick="operate(event)">Subtract</button>
<button id="multiply-button" type="button" onclick="operate(event)">Multiply</button>
<button id="divide-button" type="button" onclick="operate(event)">Divide</button>
<p id="demo" style="color:red;font-size:20px"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define global variables and additionally add onchange functions for the input, so as soon as you change the number the value changes in JS too.

```js
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').valueAsNumber;
    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').valueAsNumber;
    function updateNr(id){
        (id === 1) ? Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').valueAsNumber : Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').valueAsNumber;
    }
    function add() {
        var Total = Value1 + Value2;
        postAnswer(Total);
    }
    function sub() {
        var Total = Value1 - Value2;
        postAnswer(Total);
    }
    function mul() {
        var Total = Value1 * Value2;
        postAnswer(Total);
    }
    function div() {
        var Total = Value1 / Value2;
        postAnswer(Total);
    }
    function postAnswer(total){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
    }
```

```html
First Number: <input onchange="updateNr(1)" type="number" id="Value1"><br><br>
Second Number: <input onchange="updateNr(2)" type="number" id="Value2"><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button type="button" onclick="sub()">Subtract</button>
<button type="button" onclick="mul()">Multiply</button>
<button type="button" onclick="div()">Divide</button>
<p id="demo" style="color:red;font-size:20px"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <body style="text-align:center"><br><br>
        First Number: <input type="number" id="Value1"><br><br>
        Second Number: <input type="number" id="Value2"><br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="action(this)">Add</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="action(this)">Subtract</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="action(this)">Multiply</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="action(this)">Divide</button>
        <p id="demo" style="color:red;font-size:20px"></p>
        <script>
            action = (e) => {
                const Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').valueAsNumber;
                const Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').valueAsNumber;
                let Total = null;
                switch(e.textContent) {
                    case 'Add':
                       Total = Value1 + Value2;
                       break;
                    case 'Subtract':
                       Total = Value1 - Value2;
                       break;
                    case 'Multiply':
                       Total = Value1 * Value2;
                       break;
                    case 'Divide':
                       Total = Value1 / Value2;
                       break;
                }
                
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = `Total: ${Total}`;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

We dont need to write each function for each calculation, Try to reuse the code insted of re-writing it, Since you are trying to execute the same logic but only the arithmetic operators are changed in each function you defined, we can write a single function and change the operators depending on the calculations we intend to perform. Below code uses function `calculate(operation)` which takes ***operation*** as a parameter and gives us the result depending on the argument passed.

> Always try to use `let` insted of `var` as `let` has block scope but `var` doesn't
> Also for better code readability and consistency follow naming conventions to name your variables

```js
function calculate(operation){
    let total;
    
    let value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').valueAsNumber;
    let value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').valueAsNumber;
    
    if(operation == 'add') total = value1 + value2;
    else if(operation == 'sub') total = value1 - value2;
    else if(operation == 'multiply') total = value1 * value2;
    else if(operation == 'devide') total = value1 / value2;

    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center"><br><br>
    First Number: <input type="number" id="Value1"><br><br>
    Second Number: <input type="number" id="Value2"><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="calculate('add')">Add</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="calculate('sub')">Subtract</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="calculate('multiply')">Multiply</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="calculate('devide')">Divide</button>
    <p id="demo" style="color:red;font-size:20px"></p>
</body>
```